# Rails fixtures and functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I have a user scaffold based off of railscasts authentication from scratch and it uses the password attribute, how would I allow the test to pass and make my fixtures with password not being a field in the table while password_hash and password_salt are?
I have in the model the following code, and it is the first line that I believe causes user to not be incremented. How can I fix this?

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

I think I found the issue but have no idea how to fix it. I call the following code and it doesn't include password or password_confirmation even though I try to add it to the attributes.

```
post :create, user: @user.attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the password in the controller like this:

```
@user = User.new
@user.name = params[:user][:name]
@user.password = params[:user][:password]
```

If you still want to do like this:

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
```

add this line to the user model:

```
attr_accessible :password
```

Note that attr_accessible might lead to a security hole. Learn more about attr_accessible & attr_protected before using them.